# Winsock2 + OpenSSL in C++: How can I catch their exceptions?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, exception, openssl

I want to catch exceptions thrown when using sockets from Winsock2 with OpenSSL encryption, but I can't figure out how to do it. In C# I can just catch the base class Exception, but in C++ trying to catch them with "catch(std::exception e)" just doesn't work. It only worked with "catch(...)", but I need some object to get details from.

Is it impossible in C++ to catch each and every kind of exception by creating a catch block for the base class std::exception or am I getting exceptions derived from some other base class?

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenSSL when an error occurs, more detailed information is stored in the "error queue". The simplest thing you can do with the error queue is to print the entire queue. This can be done with `ERR_print_errors_fp()` to print the error queue. Are you using C++ wrapper around it? Please note that C++ exceptions are framework specific in most cases. There are many examples where framework exceptions are not derived from `std::exception`. For example in MFC all exceptions are derived from `CException` which has nothing to do with `std::exception`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind when unknown errors occur again. About wrapping: I am calling those functions from within a class object's methods and keep various connection-related parameters as member variables, but I'm not sure if that completely fits the definition of wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, winsock and OpenSSL are C based projects, and as such don't throw C++ exceptions.

That said, it's possible for these projects to *raise* structured exceptions.  For example, an access violation exception might be raised by the operating system if a bad buffer is passed to a function exported by one of these projects.

While its possible to [catch such exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you probably don't want to - the state of the application that raised the exception may not be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind when unknown errors occur again.

Answer (score 1):

You even can throw an integer as "exception object" in c++. So ... there is no common base class for exceptions.
You will have to look into the library documentation, which you are using, and search for possible exceptions.
If you are using Visual Studio, you could tell the debugger to stop, when an exception gets thrown (Main menu->Debug->Exceptions ... or just look into your "Output window" and search for the thrown exception type).